# Nuxt Routing: Child Pages not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am building a Nuxt app that uses the WordPress REST API for content. All my other routes work fine, but I'm coming unstuck when it comes to nested pages.

I'm using the following structure in my Nuxt app:

pages
--- _slug
  ------ index.vue

In WordPress, an example would be:

How To Get There (slug: how-to-get-there)
-- Roads & Road Safety (slug: roads-road-safety)

I must be misunderstanding how routing works as this doesn't work and I get a 404 error when attempting to access the child page.

What is the correct way to route a child page from WordPress?

Comment: What url do you use?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtlasik I use /parent/slug/ - eg: /how-to-get-here/roads-road-safety

Comment: Could you go more detail? I think you re not following the guideline from what i see from question. Could you take a photo or draw the folder `pages` structure ?

Comment: @HoangTranSon What additional detail do you need?

Comment: @AlxTheRed Give me the structure of `pages`. you should point out children folder and file vue. So that I can help you.

Comment: @AlxTheRed `_slug` is folder ??? and your url `/parent/slug/ - eg: /how-to-get-here/roads-road-safety` is not matching to the structure in your question.

Comment: @HoangTranSon Yes, _slug is a folder, I have many pages with child pages so I wanted it to be dynamic, as I can't be sure in advance which of the pages will have children. The example is just one of these - how-to-get-here is the parent page, roads-road-safety is the child. I have also tried it with manually set folders (i.e. 'how-to-get-here') and it returns file not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185873/discussion-between-hoang-tran-son-and-alxthered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read this from guideline of Nuxt.

"To define a dynamic route with a parameter, you need to define a .vue file OR a directory prefixed by an underscore."

So it should be

```
pages/ 
--| _slug/ 
-----| _slug.vue
```

Ref: [Routing in Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/)